# php regex extract pattern but only the number inside it

Tags: php, regex

I get data via a web service that I need to parse to find some value (sunshine duration) and this in php. My idea would be to do it with regex.

I can already find the desired pattern `sunshine: 7.5 h`, but I only need the `7.2` (as a number actually) out of the found match. What would be the most straight forward way to do this in PHP?

Can I do it in one `pre_match`, or will I need to to 2 x `pre_match` (second one on the match of the first one)?

**My code:**

```
//test data
$testInputs = array (
    0 => "blabla sunshine: 7 h blabla",
    1 => "blabla sunshine: 7.5 h blabla",
    2 => "blabla sunshine: 0.5 h blabla"
    );
//pattern
$pattern = '/sunshine: [\d]*.?[\d]*/';
//test
foreach($testInputs as $testInput)
 {
 preg_match($pattern, $testInput, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
 print($testInput);
 print_r($matches);
 print("<br>");
 }
```

**output**

```
sunshine: 7 h Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => sunshine: 7 [1] => 1 ) ) 
sunshine: 7.5 h Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => sunshine: 7.5 [1] => 1 ) ) 
sunshine: 0.5 h Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => sunshine: 0.5 [1] => 1 ) )
```

Comment: what if someone entered `7,5` instead of `7.5` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add brackets to captured desired digits:

```
'/sunshine: ([\d]*.?[\d]*)/'
```

The performs your `preg_match` without `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE`:

```
preg_match($pattern, $testInput, $matches);
```

And in your `matches[1]` array you will found the desired result.

Comment: Woaw that simple, how could I miss that. Thanks @fusion3k, works perfectly!